# h.263 amd MPEG-4 ASP encoders in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to use encoders H.263 and MPEG-4 ASP, but am not finding them in ffmpeg. Can anyone please help? I am using ffmpeg on windows

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands to tell you the formats and codecs that your install of ffmpeg supports:

```
ffmpeg -formats
ffmpeg -codecs
```

If you don't see those 2 formats in either of these commands, then your install of ffmpeg does not support them. You can try recompiling ffmpeg with flags to support these formats.

Comment: The default one packaged with your particular os may not come with every format installed (since that would make ffmpeg quite a large program). If you compile ffmpeg yourself, you can choose which formats you want.